# PInvoke FbwfFindFirst - FbwfCacheDetail problems

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, marshalling

I'm trying to create a PInvoke for [`FbwfFindFirst`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/aa940892%28v%3dwinembedded.5%29) and am struggling with the struct [`FbwfCacheDetail`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/aa940892%28v%3dwinembedded.5%29).

In short, I'm not sure how to marshal `WCHAR fileName[1];` seeing as it's a variable length array and a non-null terminated.

Any help would be welcomed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simon Mourier's answer is 99% correct, and with normal APIs it would have definitely worked, but it appears as if this particular API doesn't follow "normal rules", whatever that might be ;). As such, I needed to modify a couple things and this is what worked for me:

```
const int ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = 122;
const int ERROR_MORE_DATA = 234;

var volume = "C:";
var fileName = string.Empty;
var size = 0;

while (true)
{
    var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size); // FbwfFindFirst fails if given IntPtr.Zero - regardless of what the value of size is.

    try
    {
        var result = FbwfFindFirst(volume, ptr, ref size);

        // Despite documentation saying otherwise, it can return either of these
        if (result == ERROR_MORE_DATA || result == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (result != 0)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Failed with {result}");
        }

        // get the easy part 
        var detail = (FbwfCacheDetail) Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(FbwfCacheDetail));

        // compute filename offset and get the string
        // file name length is in bytes, per documentation
        fileName = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(ptr + Marshal.OffsetOf(typeof(FbwfCacheDetail), "fileName").ToInt32(), detail.fileNameLength / 2);
        break;
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Forgot to say that the pinvoke for `FbwfFindFirst` needs to be as follows, else it will return `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`:

```
[DllImport("fbwflib.dll")]
public static extern uint FbwfFindFirst(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]    
    string volume,
    IntPtr cacheDetail,
    ref int size
);
```

Comment: So my code works as is, doesn't it? Plus you allocate a 0 size buffer, (and don't release it) which is technically ok, but strange

Comment: No, your code doesn't work because the first call (to find out the size) will fail with `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` if I pass `IntPtr.Zero`, that's why I need to allocate a 0 size buffer at the start - and it is being released in the finally.

Comment: There's also a small little thing in the sense that despite documentation saying that if the buffer is too small it will return `ERROR_MORE_DATA`, I've never actually seen it returning that - instead it returns `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER` (you didn't do error checking so it would have worked either way, but just saying).

Comment: And lastly, one other thing I forgot but have edited the answer is that the pinvoke for `FbwfFindFirst` needs to have `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] ` on the `string volume` parameter else it will give out `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`.

Comment: Really don't understand the down vote. Would you have me accept an answer that effectively does not work? So that the next poor soul coming here with the exact same problem would just go "It don't work!" on the comments? Or ... would you have me research what a proper working solution is and then ask @SimonMourier to edit his answer to match **my working solution** so I can mark his answer as correct and give him the points for **my research**? Yes, he could have easily gotten there if he had the dll. Yes, his answer did help and it got up voted. But his answer does *not* work, mine does.

Comment: FYI, I didn't downvoted. But IMHO, if were you, I would have asked you to just update your answer if needed and accepted it, especially because I can't test your code (the dll is an old one) and the error check doesn't invalidate my answer (I didn't check the error on purpose), plus I used CharSet=Unicode in DllImport, you seem to have overlooked that. Are you sure my code doesn't work as is?

Comment: @SimonMourier Your code doesn't work because calling `FbwfFindFirst(volume, IntPtr.Zero, ref size);` fails with `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`. I *cannot* pass `IntPtr.Zero` else it will immediately fail, which is why I'm allocating a 0 size buffer. Like I said above, this is the main problem with your code.

Comment: @SimonMourier btw, I never said you were the one that downvoted. I just pointed out that your solution doesn't work and I had to devise my own and while it is based on yours (which is why I up voted yours) it is (imho) an entirely new answer that took me time to research, test and work out exactly what worked. If it was just a quick "ohh btw, there's a typo/bug here" ofc I'd ask you to change it, but it's more than that and it took me time to figure out myself!

Comment: @SimonMourier also, it works just with `CharSet=Unicode` - I missed that in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since the whole structure is of variable size, one way to do this is like this (I can't test it because I don't have this dll on my system):

```
string volume = "";

int size = 0;
// ask for whole structure size
FbwfFindFirst(volume, IntPtr.Zero, ref size); // this call should return ERROR_MORE_DATA which is ok

// allocate for the structure
var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
try
{
    FbwfFindFirst(volume, ptr, ref size); // should not return error

    // get the easy part 
    var detail = Marshal.PtrToStructure<FbwfCacheDetail>(ptr);

    // compute filename offset and get the string
    // file name length is in bytes, per documentation
    var fileName = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(ptr + Marshal.OffsetOf<FbwfCacheDetail>("fileName").ToInt32(), detail.fileNameLength / 2);
}
finally
{
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
}

[DllImport("fbwflib", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern int FbwfFindFirst(string volume, IntPtr cacheDetail, ref int size);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct FbwfCacheDetail
{
    public int cacheSize;
    public int openHandleCount;
    public int fileNameLength;
    byte fileName; // don't use this member
}
```

Comment: For the most part this works, but I needed to make a few adjustments. I'll share what worked for me in a separate answer for the record.