# Marshal.AllocHGlobal(0) - Why does this not return IntPtr.Zero

Tags: c#, .net, marshalling

Just trying to understand if this makes any sense and where the sense in it might be.

`Marshal.AllocHGlobal(int cb)` allocates the specified number of bytes in unmanaged memory.

But why does `Marshal.AllocHGlobal(0)` actually return an `IntPtr` that is *not* `IntPtr.Zero`? And am I supposed to free the allocated 0 bytes when I'm done using 0 bytes?

I can't see the logic behind this implementation, can someone explain it?

Comment: I *think* it returns null for 0.

Comment: @TravisJ no, it returns an actual address space. And multiple calls will result in different addresses. Like what you'd expect from a non-0 value being passed.

Comment: I think that may be processor dependent. What computer chip are you running this on?

Comment: if you want this behaviour... code it locally, i.e. `var addr = size == 0 ? IntPtr.Zero : Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);`

Comment: @MarcGravell Actually I am dealing with an unmanaged code function that I need to call twice - first to find out how much memory I need to allocate, second to get the actual values back -, but if in the first call I pass `IntPtr.Zero` it fails with `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`. So I need to have an `IntPtr` that is not 0 and `Marshal.AllocHGlobal(0)` does that, but I am just trying to understand the logic behind this working to begin with (at the `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` level that is)

Comment: @cogumel0 - that doesn't sound like the type of function where you need to be using `AllocHGlobal` at all, since it sounds like you're responsible for both *allocating* and *deallocating* the buffer. You only generally need the `AllocXxx`/`FreeXxx` functions in `Marshal` if one side of the managed/unmanaged divide is doing the allocation and the other side is responsible for freeing.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, see the function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52058173/pinvoke-fbwffindfirst-fbwfcachedetail-problems). When trying to test that answer and passing `IntPtr.Zero` on the first call I get `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`, but if I alloc 0 bytes and pass the received `IntPtr`, it works.

Comment: AllocHGlobal does not do much by itself, it merely directly calls an OS function to allocate memory.  That function has to keep a *lot* of people happy, it is the allocator that is used in practically every language runtime.  For languages that don't consider it a problem to allocate 0 bytes.  They all do, C# does as well.  `new byte[0]` is just fine and not treated specially.  They must do, having to write special code just because, say, a SQL query returned 0 rows would be a never-ending source of bugs.

Comment: And yes, having to call FreeHGlobal is a hard requirement.  The OS does not actually allocate 0 bytes, [this web page](http://www.nobugs.org/developer/win32/debug_crt_heap.html) gives a good overview of what happens under the hood.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### 1. Why does `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` not return `IntPtr.Zero` if 0 bytes are allocated?

`Marshal.AllocHGlobal` internally calls the WinAPI function [`LocalAlloc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-localalloc) from `WinBase.h`.

As to why `Marshal.AllocHGlobal(0)` does not return `IntPtr.Zero`:
`LocalAlloc` only returns `NULL` (C# equivalent: `IntPtr.Zero`) in case of a failure during the allocation.
This can also be seen in the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/marshal.cs,1194):

```
IntPtr pNewMem = Win32Native.LocalAlloc_NoSafeHandle(LMEM_FIXED, unchecked(numBytes));

if (pNewMem == IntPtr.Zero) {
    throw new OutOfMemoryException();
}
return pNewMem;
```

---

#### 2. Why does allocating 0 bytes return a (valid) memory adress?

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-localalloc) says about the return value of `LocalAlloc`:

> If the function succeeds, the return value is a handle to the newly allocated memory object.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is `NULL`.

Now, `LocalAlloc` **fails only if‡ `uBytes` is negative**; it has no problem with positive or zero values.

What that means is that allocation will always succeed‡ and you will always receive a valid pointer if you try to allocate 0 bytes.

<sub>‡ There are other reasons for failing, e.g. insufficient memory. For simplicity, they were left out in this explanation.</sub>

---

#### 3. Should I free the memory allocated by `Marshal.AllocHGlobal(0)`?

The signature of `LocalAlloc` is this:

```
DECLSPEC_ALLOCATOR HLOCAL LocalAlloc(
  UINT   uFlags,
  SIZE_T uBytes
);
```

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-localalloc) states that

> if [`uBytes`] is zero and the `uFlags` parameter specifies `LMEM_MOVEABLE`, the function returns a handle to a memory object that is marked as discarded.

For some reason, `Marshal.AllocHGlobal(0)` does **not** pass `LMEM_MOVEABLE` but rather `LMEM_FIXED` instead.

The documentation lacks information on this specific case. Running tests (see below) have shown that memory is in fact being allocated, and you definitely need to free the memory as shown below:

```
IntPtr zeroBytesPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(0);

// Do stuff with the pointer.

Marshal.FreeHGlobal(zeroBytesPtr);
```

If `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` passed `LMEM_MOVEABLE` instead, there would not be the need to free the pointer anywhere.

---

As for the tests:

```
while(true) {
    void* v = LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, 0);
}
```

allocates memory for every iteration of the loop and returns a new address each time, while

```
while(true) {
    void* v = LocalAlloc(LMEM_MOVEABLE, 0);
}
```

allocates memory only once and returns **the same address every time**.

This indicates why the memory allocated by `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` must be freed (as it uses `LMEM_FIXED`), because a new memory object is allocated with each call.

Comment: The handle to a memory object that is marked as discarded is only returned if `uFlags` specifies `LMEM_MOVEABLE` according to the documentation. What flags does `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` give? This still doesn't answer the question about whether the memory should be freed.

Comment: @cogumel0 important point, thank you. FYI: `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` specifies `LMEM_FIXED` - the documentation of `LocalAlloc` does not give information about that case. Please give me some more time to run some tests. I will edit my answer afterwards.

Comment: It looks like `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` does not pass `LMEM_MOVEABLE`. See [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/marshal.cs,1192)

Comment: @cogumel0 exactly, that's exactly why you need to free the memory. If `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` passed `LMEM_MOVABLE`, there would be no need to free the returned pointer.

Comment: Could you please edit the quote to include the full quote and re-word the answer a bit around that? How it currently stands makes it sound like it is the case that in .NET a handle to a memory object that is marked as discarded will be returned when trying to alloc 0 bytes.

Comment: @cogumel0 Edited my answer. Please see whether it is more understandable that way. I also addressed the question about whether the memory needs to be freed or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179008/discussion-between-cogumel0-and-thomas-flinkow).

Answer (score 1):

It may be important for some use cases that two distinct calls to `AllocHGlobal` never return the *same* `IntPtr` value (absent any `FreeHGlobal` calls), even if two of the calls happen to specify a somewhat nonsense size value.

At the end of the day, you're calling this function presumably for interop purposes with unmanaged code that is expecting to work with the "global" heap. And [`GlobalAlloc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-globalalloc) has long been stated to accept a `0` value, and the function always actually performs some allocation (if it succeeds).

Comment: So are you saying that if you get a `IntPtr` that is not `IntPtr.Zero` (meaning it succeeded), it's always necessary to free the memory even if we allocated 0 bytes?

Comment: @cogumel0 - yes, yes it is. Every successful call to `AllocHGlobal` needs to be matched with a `FreeHGlobal` or moral equivalent. Even one for "0" size (because there is always some actual allocation occurring)